# Wamp Server - Save

Tags: load, save, wamp

I have Wamp Server on my old machine with a load of databases in it.

1. How do I do a complete save of all these databases?
2. Once I load Wamp Server onto my new machine, how do I reload my entire databases into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your old machine, using phpMyAdmin you should `Export` all your databases i.e. Do a Backup.

Save these backups somewhere you wont loose them.

On the new machine you do the reverse, use phpMyAdmin to do an `Import` of each of your previously Exported databases i.e. Do A Restore.

*It amazes me that people have managed to create multiple databases that they would really regret loosing, but have never done any kind of backup.*

I suggest you do not scrap the old machine until you are sure you have all the databases restored on the new machine!!!!

Comment: Thanks. Previously I had just rebuilt these databases by hand. But over the years they have just grown and it has suddenly dawned on me what a mammoth task that would be. Thanks again. Now just to work out what to do with my Visual Studio Databases. Another question I think. :)